# Understanding MakeFile for STM32 app

Tags: assembly, makefile, build, embedded, stm32

I am trying to develop an app on a STM32. I am a newbie and spending some time over how to build the environment to get started. On the internet , I found a source code for an app that runs on the same platform. But have no idea how to build and environment for this and build a bin file. I see the MakeFile but I dont understand much.

I would like to know whether I can reverse engineer the build environment by keenly understanding the make file. I am sorry If I sound really stupid. Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If we could see the Makefile we would be better equipped to guess whether you can understand it. And if you asked specifically about hard-to-understand pieces of it, the chance of getting help would be even more.

Comment: I a ready to ready the make manual and learn about it more. But my question is would it be worth to dig more into the makefile I received to help me build an environment ? Or should i just leave the make file and start building an environment by myself?

Answer (score 0):

The general way to understand something that you don't know anything about is educating yourself about the subject. In the particular case I suggest reading the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), which will teach you the basics and the more advanced parts of `make` operation and `Makefile` syntax.

O'Reilly also has a book, *Managing Projects with GNU make* (3rd ed.), if you like dead tree copies.